# Is it possible to remove drop shadow from Panel in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Im trying to remove drop shadow from Panel in flex. But i didnt find proper method.any idea guys?

Comment: Create custom skin and remove it.

Comment: This one is working

dropShadowVisible="false"

<s:Panel id="lagend" dropShadowVisible="false"/>

Comment: I had not read this comment, is correct Eranga Lakmal Perera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have change the style "dropShadowEnabled" to false.

`<mx:Panel dropShadowEnabled="false" width="100" height="100"/>`